# PHP DateTime supported formats

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Does php support **"13 Sep 2014 00:35:23:440"** datetime format ? And if, how can I convert this datetime to mysql ISO supported format Y-m-d H:i:s?

Comment: [Date/Time formats supported by PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) are all documented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MySql have `YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS` format you can achieve it using `DateTime` function of PHP as

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d M Y H:i:s:u', '13 Sep 2014 00:35:23:440');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/378208)